# delete from database entry PHP script deletes all entries

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to add a delete function for my blog where the logged in user can click on the delete link, but it just does not work.
this is the form for display:

```
    <div id= "blogtitle"><?php echo $title; ?></div><div id= "date"><?php echo $date; ?></div>
    <div id="contant"> <?php echo $contant; ?> </div> <a href="deleteblog.php"> <p>Delete</p></a>
```

this is the deleteblog.php:

```
delete('blog', $_GET['id']);
header('Location: index.php');
die();
```

and this is the function:

```
function delete($blog, $id){
$blog = mysql_real_escape_string($blog);
$id = (int)$id;
mysql_query("DELETE FROM '{$blog}' WHERE 'id' = {$id}");
}
```

It just does not delete it, I've made it to work before where it did delete all the entries but it still wasn't what I intended it to do.

Comment: try to use `$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM '{$blog}' WHERE 'id' = {$id}") or die(mysql_error())` to see the cause of the problem where the `die` statement will print out the issue.

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions. Those are deprecated. Use PDO or Mysqli instead.

Comment: You aren't passing the $_GET variable in your delete link, so the delete('blog', $_GET['id']); line fails as there is no $_GET['id'] set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have pass the id in delete link

```
    <div id="contant"> <?php echo $contant; ?> </div> <a href="deleteblog.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?> "> <p>Delete</p></a>
```

Comment: i have changed that line to what you have given me and i have also changed the delete function to:

   ` 'function delete($blog, $id){
    $blog = mysql_real_escape_string($blog);
    $id = (int)$id;
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM $blog WHERE id = $id");
    }`

and now it comes up saying that the id varieble is unidentify in my anchor tags... :<

Comment: instead  of give $id to table primary key id

Comment: so do i have to change the function or the anchor tags?

Comment: you have change in anchor tag

Comment: `<div id="contant"> <?php echo $contant; ?> </div> <a href="deleteblog.php?id=<?php echo 'id'; ?> "> <p>Delete</p></a>` thats the anchor tag now

`function delete($blog, $id){
$blog = mysql_real_escape_string($blog);
$id = (int)$id;
mysql_query("DELETE FROM $blog WHERE id = $id");
}
`  thats the function, there is no error it just does not delete it, maybe my deleteblog.php is wrong? :
`delete('blog', $_GET['id']);
header('Location: index.php');
die();
  `

Comment: <div id="contant"> <?php echo $contant; ?> </div> <a href="deleteblog.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?> "> <p>Delete</p></a>

Comment: your function is correct. you have to pass the corresponding record primay key id

Comment: I've changed it to what you have given me, still it just reloads the page, have you got any ideas why this happens?

Comment: `<div id="contant"> <?php echo $contant; ?> </div> <a href="deleteblog.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?> "> <p>Delete</p></a>` and `function delete($blog, $id){
$blog = mysql_real_escape_string($blog);
$id = (int)$id;
mysql_query("DELETE FROM $blog WHERE id = $id");
}
`

Comment: $id where its come from? its in declared any where ? like $contant?

Comment: it works now, my bad haha thank you. Been looking at the code wondering for too long i've missed the obvoius stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Arun answer is correct. As a plus stop using mysql old functions and use mysqli functions instead. Or even better use PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function delete($blog, $id){
$blog = mysql_real_escape_string($blog);
$id = (int)$id;
mysql_query("DELETE FROM $blog WHERE id = $id");
}
```

And you should pass id in your anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

i have changed that line to what you have given me and i have also changed the delete function to:

`'function delete($blog, $id){
    $blog = mysql_real_escape_string($blog);
    $id = (int)$id;
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM $blog WHERE id = $id");
    }`

and now it comes up saying that the id varieble is unidentify in my anchor tags... :<